# What are some general ways to design a propositional formula representing a function?

Tags: propositional-calculus

In my discrete math course we learned that when f is a finite function then there is a formula F in propositional logic such that:

F(x,y) is true iff f(x)=y

My question is, how do I construct such formula, other than some heuristic methods? In particular I'm asked to construct a formula for : 
$$f: \mathbb{Z}_{8} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{8} $$
$$ f(x)=x^2$$
where the numbers are encoded in 3 bits binary number, so the formula contains 6 variables, 3 for input and 3 for output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always the brute force way. You can list all your results $f(x_1x_2x_3)=y_1y_2y_3$:

\begin{align}
&f(\color{red}{000})=\color{blue}{000},\qquad f(001)=001,\qquad f(010)=100,\\
&f(011)=001,\qquad f(100)=000,\qquad f(101)=001,\\
&f(110)=100,\qquad f(111)=001.
\end{align}

Then your $F(x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3)$ can be given by connecting all valid combinations with disjunction:

\begin{align}
&(x_1=\color{red}0\land x_2=\color{red}0\land x_3=\color{red}0\land y_1=\color{blue}0\land y_2=\color{blue}0\land y_3=\color{blue}0)\\
\lor\; &(x_1=0\land x_2=0\land x_3=1\land y_1=0\land y_2=0\land y_3=1)\\
\lor\; &(x_1=0\land x_2=1\land x_3=0\land y_1=1\land y_2=0\land y_3=0)\\
&\qquad\qquad\vdots\\
\lor\; &(x_1=1\land x_2=1\land x_3=1\land y_1=0\land y_2=0\land y_3=1).\\
\end{align}

Now you have at least a formula $-$ a very long one though. You can try to simplify. In this example you can reach at something like this:

$$y_2=0\land y_3=x_3\land(y_1=1\leftrightarrow(x_2=1\land x_3=0)).$$

But I admit I found it by looking closely at the table of values instead of the long formula.

Comment: That is what’s I’m looking for. Actually I knew this answer yesterday, after reading the lecture note more carefully, didn’t have time to write an answer though. Thanks !

Comment: Actually you can write x=0 as (not x) and x=1 as x, because I think “=“ is not a valid symbol in propositional logic.

Comment: @TungNguyen Yes, rigorously speaking these are no propositional formulas. But you can easily translate them as you explained. And $x=y$ is the same as $(x\land y)\lor (\neg x\land \neg y)$ or short $\neg(x\oplus y)$ where $\oplus$ is XOR. And of course I wanted to highlight the binary digits colorful ;).